# Go back automatically to previous page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

is there any solution to go back to previous page automatically without reloading the previous page?

I have index.php page full of jquery dropdown list, and after last dropdown list, there is a form to edit data. After editing data and successfully added to database I want to go back to index.php without losing selected dropdown list before.

I try meta http-equiv refresh but no luck. I also try javascript function to call history.go(-1) after specific time but it seems no work also.

It can be done if I create a href link to history.go(-1), but I want it to be automatically.

Any solution for this?

Comment: After editing data and successfully added to database ... why don't you use jquery iframe post or just ajax to process the formhandling?

Comment: ajax is best solution since pages don't maintain state. Otherwise you would need to store state and reconfigure settings

Comment: thanks for suggestion, just hear that there is jquery iframe post

Comment: you can have a cookie set with url value of previous page, and redirect to it, however I'm not sure if the state of all the dropdowns will be same

Answer (score 0):

history.go(-1) automatically?

[Like this?](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=history.go(-1)+javascript)

[I'm feeling lucky](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_go.asp)

Feel free to connect it to anything, doesn't need to be a button.